# Why is a readonly tuple's length writable?

Tags: typescript

A readonly array has a `readonly length`:

```
type Test1 = Pick<readonly string[], 'length'>; // { readonly length: number }
```

A readonly tuple doesn't:

```
type Test2 = Pick<readonly [number?], 'length'>; // { length: 0 | 1 }
declare const x: readonly [number?];
x.length = 0; // wat
```

Why is this? It seems contrary to the purpose of `readonly`.

Comment: Seems like an oversight to me; unless there's already discussion of it in GitHub (which I can't find) then any answer here will probably just be conjecture/opinion which is not generally appropriate Stack Overflow.  (My conjecture: a fixed-length tuple doesn't need a readonly length because it can only have one value, but tuples with optional elements have a union of lengths and open-ended tuples were overlooked) Maybe someone (you?) should open [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) asking what's going on...

Comment: Of course, you can make it `readonly` yourself in the meantime: `type ROLengh<T extends { length: number }> = T & { readonly length: T['length'] };`

Comment: Thanks, that was my best guess as well, but i often like to know i didn't make a simple mistake, before bothering TS maintainers with bug-issues. I'll probably make an issue later, when i have time.  There is a backlog due to [holidays](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47154) currently anyways, so there is no reason to hurry. Towards the other point, no, intersection types are different, especially for tuples. E.g. any homomorphic mapped types, and out-of-bounds checks, immediately break under intersection with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug and is [fixed in TS 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#readonly-tuples-have-a-readonly-length-property).